# Resizing Image in Python without losing letter quality

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have tried using the following code in order resize my picture, but I lose so much quality that I cannot even read the letters clearly. At first I create it the picture from a string, which has very good quality .

```
handoverNote = str.encode(handoverNote)
with open("test.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(codecs.decode(handoverNote, "base64"))

image = Image.open("test.png")
image.thumbnail((500, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save("test2.png", quality=95)
```

But after resizing the image looks unreadable or alstmost unrecognizable like in this example:

[image]

This is the original image, I get without resizing.

[image: n]

What am I doing wrong here? Is it because I use PNG?

[image: This is the original file]

Comment: could you post the original image as well

Comment: Maybe its your thumbnail conversion, try without that. `image = image.resize((500, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)`

Comment: I used image = image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS), but it still looks very bad.

Comment: I uploaded the original

Comment: Interestingly, this is a problem similar to demosaicing a Bayer pattern. Normally, downsampling (say by a factor of 2) is easy because you just take the average of each 2x2 box. But if you have small letters or other features of interest comparable in size to that box, that obviously isn't good enough. Now you have to add edge awareness, which implies frequency-based filtering. It's an interesting subject.

Comment: Try downsample it yourself. [`pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/PIL.html#module-PIL.ImageTransform) has `PIL.ImageTransform.Transform` which looks like it can scale an image down. Otherwise `PIL.ImageTransform.AffineTransform` passing something like `(0.25, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0)` as `matrix`